# add timestamp to top command batch output

Tags: bash, timestamp, append, puid

I need to add timestamp to the beginning of each line printed in the following output.

```
# top -b |grep -w 'db2sysc\|java'

 4756 db2inst1  20   0 2525m 875m 830m S    0 11.0   1:33.57 db2sysc
 4951 root      20   0 1416m 689m 7276 S    0  8.7   1:27.86 java
 4756 db2inst1  20   0 2525m 875m 830m S    1 11.0   1:33.61 db2sysc
 4951 root      20   0 1416m 689m 7276 S    0  8.7   1:27.87 java
```

would like it like this

```
1366138603 4756 db2inst1  20   0 2525m 875m 830m S    0 11.0   1:33.57 db2sysc
1366138603 4951 root      20   0 1416m 689m 7276 S    0  8.7   1:27.86 java
1366138692 4756 db2inst1  20   0 2525m 875m 830m S    1 11.0   1:33.61 db2sysc
1366138692 4951 root      20   0 1416m 689m 7276 S    0  8.7   1:27.87 java
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: which timestamp? when the process was started? or just simply the current time?

Comment: current time, got the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using `awk` instead of `grep`:

```
top -b | awk '/db2sysc|java/ {print systime(), $0}'
```

Comment: +1 if OP needs systime. `" "` could be `,`. 
and thx for the tips.. :)

Comment: I normally use `" "`, so I can easily change the separator when needed, but in this case `,` is probably the better option. Fixed.